# Voyager Admin Panel Bulk Update With Old Data

Tags: javascript, php, voyager

I am using the bulkUpdate library for Voyager Admin Panel. I am currently facing the problem where when choosing the rows to update, I will need to pass a specific status to my formfield for some extra processing at my formfield. However, my problem is when I bulkUpdate, a new modal is created and cannot be updated using the status I grabbed. Any ideas on how to pass my "Status" to my formfield blade?

I tried to call from JS to update the PHP but failed.
AJAX and controller doesn't seem to work for my case since the formfield.blade is included in my current file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.